# Lyx 2.2.3 AEA Template Error - 'Here definitely' does not work

Tags: floats, lyx, templates, document-classes

Begging for any kind of help. I am working on a paper in Lyx by using AEA template after I loaded unavailable class with following link (https://wiki.lyx.org/Examples/AEA)

All others are fine, but only problem occurs when I try to hold image by using an option "Here definitely". Error messages are following:

[image]

And here is my preamble

```
\usepackage[abbr]{harvard}
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\draftSpacing{1.5}
```

I have no idea what's going on my Lyx. If I turn off the here definitely option, it works fine but all images and tables would be messy. FYI, I use windows 10 and lyx 2.2.3, very recent version. I appreciate any advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the definition of the `figure` and `table` environments in `AEA.cls` I think.  I can't explain exactly why the problem occurs, but I can suggest a fix:

Open `AEA.cls` in your favourite text editor, and go to lines 1203-04. Modify these lines from

```
           {\@float{figure}[#1]\begin{center}}
           {\end{center}\end@float}
```

to

```
           {\@float{figure}[#1]\centering}
           {\end@float}
```

I.e. change `\begin{center}` to `\centering` and remove `\end{center}`. Do the same modification for lines 1206-07, 1210-11, 1220-21, 1223-24 and 1227-28.

Comment: @floater No worries. You might consider [accepting the answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking the checkmark on the left.

Comment: My apology. It's my first time to post here. Anyway thanks!!!

Comment: @floater thanks for accepting the answer. Note that you can also "upvote" (click on the up arrow) if you found the answer useful.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I'm planning to propose that we put a LyX note in the template file by the table float that we include, along the lines of "If you select <<Here definitely>>, you may need a workaround suggested at <<link to this answer>>". Let me know if you suggest any other details to add.

Comment: @scottkosty (You need 15 rep points to upvote.) Don't have any other suggestions at the moment.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. ah thanks, I've forgotten that a few times.